# Returning value (reference, pointer and object)

Tags: c++, optimization, copy, return, return-value-optimization

I have some difficulties with understanding what is really done behind returning values in C++.

Let's have following code:

```
class MyClass {

public:

    int id;

    MyClass(int id) {
        this->id = id;
        cout << "[" << id << "] MyClass::ctor\n";
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass& other) {
        cout << "[" << id << "] MyClass::ctor&\n";
    }

    ~MyClass() {
        cout << "[" << id << "] MyClass::dtor\n";
    }

    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& r) {
        cout << "[" << id << "] MyClass::operator=\n";
        return *this;
    }

};

MyClass foo() {
    MyClass c(111);  
    return c;        
}

MyClass& bar() {
    MyClass c(222);
    return c;
}

MyClass* baz() {
    MyClass* c = new MyClass(333);
    return c;
}
```

I use gcc 4.7.3.

**Case 1**

When I call:

```
MyClass c1 = foo();
cout << c1.id << endl;
```

The output is:

```
[111] MyClass::ctor
111
[111] MyClass::dtor
```

My understanding is that in `foo` object is created on the stack and then destroyed upon return statement because it's end of a scope. Returning is done by object copying (copy constructor) which is later assigned to `c1` in main (assignment operator). If I'm right why there is no output from copy constructor nor assignment operator? Is this because of RVO?

**Case 2**

When I call:

```
MyClass c2 = bar();
cout << c2.id << endl;
```

The output is:

```
[222] MyClass::ctor
[222] MyClass::dtor
[4197488] MyClass::ctor&
4197488
[4197488] MyClass::dtor
```

What is going on here? I create variable then return it and variable is destroyed because it is end of a scope. Compiler is trying copy that variable by copy constructor but It is already destroyed and that's why I have random value? So what is actually in `c2` in main?

**Case 3**

When I call:

```
MyClass* c3 = baz();
cout << c3->id << endl;
```

The output is:

```
[333] MyClass::ctor
333
```

This is the simplest case? I return a dynamically created pointer which lies on heap, so memmory is allocated and not automatically freed. This is the case when destructor isn't called and I have memory leak. Am I right?

Are there any other cases or things that aren't obvious and I should know to fully master returning values in C++? ;) What is a recommended way to return a object from function (if any) - any rules of thumb upon that?

Comment: `MyClass c1 = foo();` is not an assignment. It's a *copy-initialization*.

Comment: Hmmm, my mistake. So in all of this cases `operator=` won't be called?

Comment: Indeed. Rules of thumb: Return by value (and rely on either copy elision or move semantics) unless you want to expose internals (like `std::vector::operator[]` returns a reference), don't return an owning raw pointer (i.e. one that must be deleted), don't return a `const` object (because that prohibits move semantics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1**:

```
MyClass foo() {
    MyClass c(111);  
    return c;        
}
...
MyClass c1 = foo();
```

is a typical case when RVO can be applied. This is called *copy-initialization* and the assignment operator is not used since the object is created in place, unlike the situation:

```
MyClass c1;
c1 = foo();
```

where `c1` is constructed, temporary `c` in `foo()` is constructed, [ copy of `c` is constructed ], `c` or copy of `c` is assigned to `c1`, [ copy of `c` is destructed] and `c` is destructed. (what exactly happens depends on whether the compiler eliminates the redundant copy of `c` being created or not).

**Case 2**:

```
MyClass& bar() {
    MyClass c(222);
    return c;
}
...
MyClass c2 = bar();
```

invokes ***undefined behavior*** since you are returning a reference to local (temporary) variable `c` ~ an object with automatic storage duration.

**Case 3**:

```
MyClass* baz() {
    MyClass* c = new MyClass(333);
    return c;
}
...
MyClass c2 = bar();
```

is the most straightforward one since *you control what happens* yet with a very unpleasant consequence: ***you are responsible for memory management***, which is the reason why you should avoid dynamic allocation of this kind always when it is possible (and prefer Case 1).

Answer (score 3):

May I just add that case #2 is one of the cases of undefined behavior in the C++ language, since returning a reference to a local variable is illegal. This is because a local variable has a precisely defined lifetime, and - by returning it by a reference - you're returning a reference to a variable that does not exist anymore when the function returns. Therefore, you exhibit undefined behavior and the value of the given variable is practically random. [As is the result of the rest of your program, since *Anything at all can happen*](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213).

Most compilers will issue a warning when you try to do something like this (either return a local variable by reference, or by address) - gcc, for example, tells me something like this :

```
bla.cpp:37:13: warning: reference to local variable ‘c’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

You should remember, however, that the compiler is not at all required to issue any kind of warning when a statement that may exhibit undefined behavior occurs. Situations such as this one, though, must be avoided at all costs, because they're practically never right.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes.
2) You have a random value because your copy c'tor and `operator=` don't copy the value of `id`. However, you are correct in assuming there is no relying on the value of an object after it has been deleted.
3) Yes.